# JavaScript issue with single page application in Safari (iOS > 9)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

We have a simple script which is intended to fire during the change event of a select box in our application.

```
if(e.type == "change") {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(e.target.id).blur();
  $(".headerLogo").focus();
}
```

When we add this this code to the onChange event of our combo, after a few attempts the browser becomes unresponsive/hung. With out this piece of code, the onChange event works - at least it will not make the browser unresponsive.

Note: this has been added to prevent a unusual behavior of select box in iOS > 9. In iOS > 9 , the select box is retaining the focus leading to some unexpected actions in the UI.

In the above code we are trying to forcefully change the focus. Any pointers to resolve this issue is verymuch appreciated.

Comment: I'm curious.  Have you tried doing like a console.log() in there to see how many times that change handler is being fired?  Though two things about this, very small, snipplet confuse me.  If you are in a change event handler, why are you checking the event type?  Also for the blur you are re-selecting the element, when you already have it with `e.target`.

Comment: When using `focus()` I prefer to use ids instead of class names to prevent jQuery to give the focus to multiple components.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code as in  [mcve]

Comment: We have tried this code in our simulators -browser stack- but couldn't reproduce the issue. We are seeing this issue in the actual device only. In our application we are using JCF jQurey plugin to create custom HTML elements. So the abode is added to the existing onChange function in the JCF jQuery plugin. In the plugin we noticed that the existing onChange event is being fired in click and change events. That is the reason behind we had to add a check for onChange.